# Rails5 Routing and conditional statements

Tags: routes, conditional-statements, ruby-on-rails-5

I wonder if anyone can help with this...its very frustrating for me.

Firstly I'm still pretty new to all of this. So apologies if I get some terminology wrong. I have completed some tutorials and am now working on my first app without any guided walkthroughs... its slow going :)

I have two groups of pages, one group where I should show a sidebar and one group that does not need it. Below are my routes...

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

#----Pages----
root 'pages#home'
get '/home', to: 'pages#home'
get '/contact', to: 'pages#contact'

#----Users----
get '/app', to: 'users#app'
get 'users/new', to: 'users#new'
get '/users', to: 'users#index'
get '/signup', to: 'users#new'
post '/signup', to: 'users#create'

#----Sessions----
get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'


#----Projects----
get'/projects/:id', to: 'projects#show'
get '/projects', to: 'projects#index'
get '/projects/new', to: 'projects#new'
post '/projects/new', to: 'projects#create'


#----Hazards----
get'/hazards/:id', to: 'hazards#show'
get '/hazards', to: 'hazards#index'
get '/hazards/new', to: 'hazards#new'

#----Resources----
resources :users
resources :projects
resources :hazards
end
```

I have the following code in my header which works fine...

```
<% if current_page?(app_path) ||
            current_page?(users_path) ||
            current_page?(projects_path) ||
            current_page?(hazards_path)
    <%= render 'layouts/sidebar' %>
<% end %>
```

it supplies a sidebar to those paths listed above and not to the others. However... I wish to add to the list above pages from the 'project_path' so /projects/6 etc. To achieve this I added the following line to the code above...

```
current_page?(project_path(:id)
```

resulting in...

```
<% if current_page?(app_path) ||
            current_page?(users_path) ||
            current_page?(projects_path) ||
            current_page?(hazards_path) ||
            current_page?(project_path(:id)) %>
    <%= render 'layouts/sidebar' %>

<% end %>
```

Once added the app loads fine but the sidebar is NOT added to the project page. So I tried an alternative method as follows...

```
current_page?(project_path(@project))
```

After this amendment the project page now shows the sidebar correctly but... all other pages that do not have the sidebar fail to load with the following error...

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"projects", :id=>nil}    missing required keys: [:id]
```

I'm at my wits end... I have also tried

```
current_page?(project_path(params.permit))
Current_page?(project_path(project))
current_page?(project_path(project(params[:id])))
```

Can someone please put me out of my misery... thats not an exaggeration... pure misery.

many thanks.

Comment: ...what if I told you that its now 03:51 in the a.m and I have work in the morning.... see I'm totally committed ... any takers

Answer (score 0):

Also this looks ugly:

```
<% if current_page?(app_path) ||
  current_page?(users_path) ||
  current_page?(projects_path) ||
  current_page?(hazards_path) ||
  current_page?(project_path(:id)) %>
<%= render 'layouts/sidebar' %>
```

Depending on your app, you could use something like a before_action:

ApplicationController:

```
def show_sidebar
  @show_it = true
end
```

ProjectsController:

```
before_action :show_sidebar, only: [:show]
```

And in view:

```
<%= render 'layouts/sidebar' if @show_sidebar %>
```

(This should work (not completely sure about syntax - newby also :) ). Can also try:

```
<% if @show_sidebar %>
  <%= render 'layouts/sidebar' %>
<% end %>
```

You could also use the same logic and replace 'true' to 'false' and in before_action method tell controller where NOT to show sidebar.

Hope this helps.

p.s. next time also show/see yourself logs, if you get wrong behaviour without an error from Rails

Comment: Hi J.D in my desperation, I posted my question on a few different forums and I seem to have added it to SO twice... it was answered here... [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718419/why-does-rails-not-recognise-project-path) Incidentally, I tidied up the code... but did it differently. I added an IF clause in the header itself and just added the render form helper

Comment: @Sergio answer is interesting and he wrote answer to only answer your question and this solution looks better now, but still I think this long OR OR OR statement is wrong. It definitely violates something in MVC, especially if u do it in a view. So I still consider my way as better, however I feel it might be done even more elegant from the ApplicationHelper.

Comment: Yeah I agreee that the OR statements are not great. At the moment I just want to get everything working in a way that I understand. There will be a second and no doubt third version where I refactor all of the code, I am also pretty sure that by that time I will rewrite most of the views for js using ember.js So at the moment I am just taking things a little slowly, thanks for helping out.