# Why does Rails not recognise project_path

Tags: routes, conditional-statements, ruby-on-rails-5

I wonder if anyone can help with this...its driving me crazy.

Firstly I'm still pretty new to all of this. So apologies if I get some terminology wrong. I have completed some tutorials and am now working on my first app without any guided walkthroughs... its slow going :)

I have two groups of pages, one group where I should show a sidebar and one group that does not need it. Below are my routes...

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

#----Pages----
root 'pages#home'
get '/home', to: 'pages#home'
get '/contact', to: 'pages#contact'

#----Users----
get '/app', to: 'users#app'
get 'users/new', to: redirect('/signup')
get '/signup', to: 'users#new'
post '/signup', to: 'users#create'

#----Sessions----
get      '/sessions/new', to: 'sessions#new'
get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'


#----Projects----


#----Hazards----


#----Resources----
resources :users
resources :projects
resources :hazards
end
```

I have the following code in my header which works fine...

```
<% if current_page?(app_path) ||
            current_page?(users_path) ||
            current_page?(projects_path) ||
            current_page?(hazards_path)
    <%= render 'layouts/sidebar' %>
<% end %>
```

it supplies a sidebar to those paths listed above and not to the others. However... I wish to add to the list above pages from the 'project_path' so /projects/6 etc. To achieve this I added the following line to the code above...

```
current_page?(project_path(:id)
```

resulting in...

```
<% if current_page?(app_path) ||
            current_page?(users_path) ||
            current_page?(projects_path) ||
            current_page?(hazards_path) ||
            current_page?(project_path(:id)) %>
    <%= render 'layouts/sidebar' %>

<% end %>
```

Once added the app loads fine but the sidebar is NOT added to the project page. So I tried an alternative method as follows...

```
current_page?(project_path(@project))
```

After this amendment the project page now shows the sidebar correctly but... all other pages that do not have the sidebar fail to load with the following error...

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"projects", :id=>nil}    missing required keys: [:id]
```

I'm at my wits end... I have also tried

```
current_page?(project_path(params.permit))
Current_page?(project_path(project))
current_page?(project_path(project(params[:id])))
```

Can someone please put me out of my misery... thats not an exaggeration... pure misery.

many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the other pages don't have a `@project`. Perhaps, you could do something like this:

```
current_page?(projects_path) ||
@project && current_page?(project_path(@project)) ||
...
```

Comment: *** ENTER EXPLETIVE HERE*** that works... can you explain why that works but the original project_path(@project) doesnt work?

Comment: @MysticChimp: It works by not entering project path check on pages which don't have `@project`. The term is "short-circuiting". Read up on it, if you're interested.

Comment: @MysticChimp: what do you mean, two days? :)

Comment: thats how long i've been searching, writing,  rewriting, generally pulling out hair etc. Thanks again